# How do I generate a Cryptographically secure number in Classic ASP?

Tags: random, asp-classic, cryptography

What's the best way to generate a cryptographically secure random number in classic ASP?

Comment: Maybe use the MicrosoftCrypto API: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI

Comment: Also, remember that you always can use jScript into classic .ASP pages. You can even mix Vbcript and jScript, by the use of #include. This can be interesting when you have to deal with function not available in VBScript, such as advanced Math (required in every serious cryptographic strategy).

Comment: Also, remember that you always can use jScript into classic .ASP pages. You can even mix Vbcript and jScript, by the use of #include. This can be interesting when you have to deal with function not available in VBScript, such as advanced Math (required in every serious cryptographic strategy).

Comment: Interesting out-of-the-box solution from a development team: Use Oracles DBMS_Crypto functions and get a cryptographically secure random number from the database.

Comment: @boy-baukema Genius! It can be done even in MS SQL Server with the CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM function, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

In many cases this helps when you want random/unique ID's: (maybe not useful if you indeed numbers)

```
Function GetGuid() 
            Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib") 
            GetGuid = Left(CStr(TypeLib.Guid), 38) 
            Set TypeLib = Nothing 
End Function 


for i = 1 to 10
    response.write GetGuid() & "<br>"
next
```